# Wont boot up after update last night

Tags: display

Question about display.  I am guessing I have an issue with driver/firmware for display.  System was fine, updated last nite....turned on HP Pavilion this morning and it will not boot. Says firmware bug with a slightly dotted green line stuck on screen.  Not sure what the update did.  This is with Elementary 38.

If I boot Elementary 37 it boots ok and my display is fine.

Can anyone provide some insight for linux newbie?  Not sure what last update did but my pc does not like it.  Booted in safe mode today and downloaded earlier update to see if it was fixed but it was not.  I am pretty new to linux...

Thanks!